# Make an application click-through

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have created a WinForm application in which, when I hit a key, it's name (or code) is displayed on a transparent form. What I want is to make this form click-through, meaning: when I click on the form or hit a key on the keyboard, I want its name to be shown on my app but also it should work on the window behind my app's form. For instance if I open a web browser, open my app and click on the area that the close button (x) of the browser is, the browser should close but my app should display: "Left button". How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This VB.net [article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12877/Transparent-Click-Through-Forms) seems to accomplish what you require.  Haven't tested it, but hope it helps.  Good Luck!

EDIT: This seems to only take care of the click-thru part of what you want to accomplish. For the key forwarding part, I would use `GetTopWindow()` and `GetNextWindow()` API functions to navigate the window stack and find out the window handle that's behind your application's Z-order, and then `SendMessage()` to forward the key press events to the window behind your app.